# so many releases... how to select (Tomcat, JDK, etc.)?

Tags: tomcat, java

When deciding to install Tomcat on a Linux CentOS 6.2 server, I'm faced with a variety of releases to select from. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Releases).  Regarding JDK releases, there are also are variety to select from (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates)).

Which brings up the question... should one generally select the latest stable release (e.g. Tomcat 7.0.25, and JDK SE 7 update 2)?  Or, should one install the last release from the last version (e.g. Tomcat 6.0.35, JDK SE 6 last update)?

What thought process do people go through in making this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple versions are supported concurrently it's usually due to a code fork and lack of backward compatibility.  Previous versions continue to be maintained for bug and security fixes only.  If you are starting from scratch, I would suggest latest-and-greatest for the most modern API.  Something else to consider, if you are working with a 3rd party application, the requirements may vary.  Check the vendor for their suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I generally download the stable release of the most recent version. Part of this is I hate having to upgrade repeatedly nor do I want to worry about whether or not changes will make it out of alpha/beta. However, the other portion of this decision is the requirements/restrictions for whatever I will be using said server for (does an app have a specific requirement, etc?).